# Create a list (length and int values defined by user input) and then find lowest value in list and exclude from proceeding calculation

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble with making a simple calculator work. There are some requirements I need to meet with it:

- Need to be able to calculate the average of however many grades the user wants
- Be able to calculate within the same program separate grade averages
  for multiple 'users'
- Give the option to exclude the lowest value entered for each person
  from their individual average calculation.

I have some code, it is pretty much a mess:

```
def main():
Numberofstudents=eval(input("How many students will enter grades today? "))
Name=input("What is your frist and last name? ")
numberofgrades=eval(input("How many grades do you want to enter? ")) 
gradecount=0
studentcount=1
lowestgradelisty=[]
while studentcount<=Numberofstudents:
    gradetotal=0
    while gradecount<numberofgrades:
        gradeforlisty=eval(input("Enter grade please: "))
        gradetotal=gradetotal+gradeforlisty
        gradecount=gradecount+1    
        Numberofstudents=Numberofstudents-1
        studentcount=studentcount+1
        lowestgradelisty.extend(gradeforlisty)
        min(lowestgradelisty.extend(gradeforlisty))
        Drop=(min(lowestgradelisty.extend(gradeforlisty))), "is your lowest grade. do you want to drop it? Enter as yes or no: "
        if (Drop=="yes"):
            print(Name, "The new total of your grades is", gradetotal-min(lowestgradelisty.append(gradeforlisty)/gradecount))
        elif (Drop=="no"):
            print("the averages of the grades enetered is", gradetotal/gradecount)            
    gradecount=0
    studentcount=1
main()
```

Comment: Split this program up into different methods and it will be easier. Build the program up piece by piece

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does what it sounds like you wanted to ask about. It removes the smallest grade and returns the new average.

```py
def avgExceptLowest(listofgrades):
    # find minimum value
    mingrade = min(listofgrades)
    # remove first value matching the minimum
    newgradelist = listofgrades.remove(mingrade)
    # return the average of of the new list
    return sum(newgradelist) / len(newgradelist)
```

A number of notes on your code:

The indentation of the code in your question is wrong. Fixing it may solve some of your problems if that's how it appears in your python file.

In Python the convention is to never capitalize a variable, and that's making your highlighting come out wrong.

If you code this correctly, you won't need any tracking variables like studentcount or gradecount. Check out [Python's list of built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) and use things like `len(lowestgradelisty)` and loops like `for i in range(0, numberofstudents):` instead to keep your place as you execute.